# using Soundex with SQL server (Contains) for searching?

Tags: sql-server

how to use Soundex with SQL server Contains for searching
so when I search for two or three word for example it help me

Comment: You need to provide some details here. As posted this is entirely too broad.

Comment: I want to use full-text search in the lambda expression and at the same time I want to use in this search the Soundex

Comment: What is preventing you? This is way too vague to offer any kind of suggestion here. Maybe this is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/